# Getting token from API response

Tags: ruby, httparty

I have an API i am connecting to and according to the documentation I am suppose to get a login_token from my 1st call to the API. I setup an initalization method with httparty and I get the token but I am not sure how to place it in my initalization method or why I cant seem to parse it correctly.

Here is the initilization method:

```
  def initialize(username,password)
    @username = username
    @password = password
    @login_token = login_token
    get_token(self.class.post("/login/", body: {username: username, password: password}).parsed_response)
  end
```

Also here is the get_token method I made that should get the token:

```
  def get_token
    if response ['success'] == 'true'
      login_token = @login_token
    else
      raise "Code: #{response["message"]}"
    end
  end
```

The response I get is like this:

```
reading all...
-> "{\n  \"login_token\": \"...token...\", \n  \"success\": true\n}"
read 99 bytes
Conn close
MultiXml::ParseError: Start tag expected, '<' not found
```

I think my error is from the parsed_response piece on the initialize method. Any ideas on what is wrong and how I can put this token into my method?

-EDIT-

At the top of this file I changed

```
format :xml
```

to

```
format :json
```

Now my error is in my get_token method. It doesn't seem to read the response correctly.

Comment: Looks like your getting JSON back, but trying to parse as XML. Not sure why that is though.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I changed the response type to json and I used the

```
instance_variable_set
```

to get it to work!

```
def get_token(response)
      response.each { |login_token, value | instance_variable_set("@#{login_token}", value ) }
  end
```